# Between in linq query using 2 tables

Tags: performance, linq, query-optimization

I have 2 tables. let first one be departmentValues
EG:

```
DepartmentValues
---------------
1
2
3
...
```

it can have upto 1000 values.

Second table be relation_values, has department from and department to
EG:

```
relation_values
---------------
deptfrom | deptto
-----------------
1          | 2
3          | 45
34         | 67
.....
```

I need to get all the department values from table departmentValues that falls under the deptfrom to deptto in realtion_values

```
foreach (var item in DepartmentValues)
            {
                foreach(var relval in relationValues)
                {
                    int chkDeptFrom = string.Compare(item, relval.relation_value_from); ;
                    int chkDeptTo = string.Compare(item, relval.relation_value_to);

                    if (chkDeptFrom >= 0 && chkDeptTo <= 0)
                    {
                        values.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But this has performance issues, how to rectify it when there are like 4000 records in departmentValues table

Comment: You should give a better glance of your tables. The second one seems to be missing the FK. Anyway, you should try joining the two tables and working with the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
departments
-----------
1
2
3
4
11
15
AttributeValues
-------------
Id  |deptTo | deptFrom
----------------
 01 | 2     | 3
 02 | 4     | 6
 
Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair>> chaptervalues = departments.Distinct().ToDictionary(key => key, departments => attributeValues.Where(x => string.Compare(departments, x.deptFrom) >= 0 && string.Compare(departments, x.deptTo) <= 0).Select(x => new KeyValuePair { key=x.id, value=x.name}).Distinct().ToList());
List<KeyValuePair> result =  chaptervalues.Values.SelectMany(x => x).DistinctBy(x=>x.key).ToList();
```

result will have the set of chaptervalues

so chaptervalues will be - 01, 02

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

U can use linq to do that

```
var a = from dv in departmentValues
            from rv in relationValues
            where dv.Value >= rv.DeptFrom && dv.Value <= rv.DeptTo 
            select dv.Value;
```

[image]